# Accessing an external remote postgres database using pgadmin4 from a local machine produce password authentication fail

Tags: database, postgresql, authentication, remote-access, pgadmin-4

I am trying to connecting to a remote database with pgadmin4 using putty to portforward so I can connect to a local database on a remote server. This works normally like a charme.

I switched computer and set up the database setting and putty the same. (db: pgpass.conf on old maching with copy&paste to new db connection setting in pgadmin4 and a configuration file export/import for putty - that is 1:1 transfair).

When trying to connect to the remote local database, on the old computer it still works and on the new one i get this error message:

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" FATAL:
>   password authentication failed for user "postgres"

On Windows 10 I don't find the password file? Is there any? What is wrong with the setting in pgadmin4?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I don't have SSL so I have to disable it, and the connection is established.

Go to the servers **properties**, select the tab **Connection** go to SSL mode and choose **Disable** - finally Save it